# Several tags that need cleaned up

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-cleanup, retag-request

I've noticed a few tags on the site need cleaned up.

Some of what I would like to see changed:

- There is a [lag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) tag and a [lagging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lagging) tag that should be merged.
- The [slow](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slow) tag should be burninated, as it is ambiguous and better tags like [lag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) already exist.
- The tag [disk-encryption](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disk-encryption) should be merged with [encryption](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption) and made a synonym.
- Merge [android-p](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-p) with [9.0-pie](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/9.0-pie) and make it a synonym.

Could the tags (shown above) be cleaned up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well spotted, thanks! I've merged all but the encryption tags. "disk encryption" definitely is an encryption – but encryption is not necessarily disk encryption. There's also FBE (file based encryption), text encryption (e.g. using GPG), encryption in messengers (e.g. OMEMO in XMPP), etc.pp., so IMHO we should better keep the two separate.